# Reverse string Python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I would like to get input from a user and then to print the string reversed like this: 
input:

> hello

output:

> o 
>  ol 
>  oll 
>  olle 
>  olleh

This is my code:

```
s = input()
for i in range(len(s) - 2, -1, -1):
    print(s[:i:-1])
```

And output i receive is:

> o 
>  ol 
>  oll 
>  olle

I am constantly missing the last character. I tried many variations of the slicing. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the full string reversed you must use `s[::-1]` omitting the first value.
Since that doesn't fit into your iteration you'll have to use something like:

```
s = input()

for i in range(len(s) - 2, -1, -1):
  print(s[:i:-1])

print(s[::-1])
```

Comment: I like this better than mine.

Comment: I think this is the easiest solution of all. I really like it, and didn't really think about using s[::-1] in the end of the for loop, I was only trying to reverse it fully through iterations. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4):

You must first obtain the substring and then reverse it:

```
s = "hello"
for i in range(len(s)-1, -1, -1):
    print(s[i:][::-1])
```

Or:

```
s = "hello"
for i, _ in enumerate(s):
    print(s[i:][::-1])
```

Or reverse the word and get the substring:

```
s = "hello"
for i, _ in enumerate(s):
    print(s[::-1][:i+1])
```

Comment: This is nice, but I don't think the double string slicing is strictly necessary.

Comment: @jpp Why do you think that double slicing is not right? What problems could it generate? :-)

Comment: Double the operations :). I'm not saying it's wrong, it's just.. not necessary.

Comment: This is cool solution, but I don't think it's necessary to use double slicing

Answer (score 2):

Easiest perhaps is to iterate from `-1` backwards:

```
s = 'hello'
for i in range(1, len(s)+1):
    print(s[-1: -i-1: -1])

hello
o
ol
oll
olle
olleh
```

The way this works, you are slicing sequentially:

- `s[-1: -2: -1]`,
- `s[-1: -3: -1]`,...
- `s[-1: -len(s)-1: -1]`

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

```
a = "Hello"
for i in range(len(a)):
    print(a[-i-1])
```

This way you are not dealing with string slices, only indexing the string and there isn't a bunch of extra numbers to figure out what they are doing.

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work as you aren't defining any slices.

Comment: I see - I missed the requirement that the whole word is backwards. This method will print out each letter individually in the reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

You could also simply reverse the complete thing and print it sliced from the start to save you some headache:

```
b = "hello"   # your input
h = b[::-1]   # inverse all - so this is now olleh

# list slicing is from:exclusive to - so simply add 1 to fit with the ranges values 0-4
for k in ( h[0:i+1] for i in range(0,len(h)) ):
    print(k)
```

Output:

```
o
ol
oll
olle
olleh
```

Answer (score 0):

The very basic method to reverse a string `s` is `s[::-1]` (and save it
in another variable, say `s2`).

Then, to print consecutive rows with increasing part of this string (`s2`),
you need a loop over `range(1, len(s2)+1)`, stating the upper limit of `s2`
(excluding).

So the script can look like below:

```
s = 'hello'
s2 = s[::-1]
for i in range(1, len(s2)+1):
    print(s2[:i])
```